# Is there any recipe to successfully install PLPython in Postgresql 9.3 64bit or 32bit on Windows 64 bits?

Tags: postgresql, plpython

running `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u` gave me the error - `The specified module could not be found` even if the file is at the correct place.

After reading everything on the web, I tried to download another python version (3.2) as suggested and replace the `dll`.

Now I receive an error about a missing magic block: missing magic block HINT: Extension libraries are required to use the PG_MODULE_MAGIC macro.

I tried the same processes with a 32 and 64 bits version of Postgresql and both failed like explained.

Is there any solution to install that PLPython on a Windows 64 bits OS?

Comment: Postgresql version 9.3

Comment: You should probably download the 64-bit version of dependency walker (depends.exe) and open `plpython3.dll` with it. See what it reports.

Comment: I installed the latest python 3.2 (3.2.5) and had no issues installing plpython3u. I'm on Windows 7 64bit. I could test on Windows Server 2008 R2 and 2012 R2 if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me (Windows 7 64-bit)

I installed Python 3.2 from here:

http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2/python-3.2.amd64.msi

Somebody screwed something up, so you need to do the following:

1. find python3.dll in C:\Python32\DLLs (or wherever you installed it)
2. copy python3.dll to python32.dll (like copy and paste it then rename it)
3. run `create extension plpython3u` in postgres

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this problem with **Postgres 9.4**, use the steps in Neil McGuigan's answer, just **with Python 3.3** ([download link](https://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/)).

Make sure to use the version corresponding to your system (64-bit in most cases).