# How to install PL/Python on PostgreSQL 9.3 x64 Windows 7?

Tags: python, postgresql, windows-7-x64, postgresql-9.3, plpython

I have tried to install the PL/Python v2.x language inside PostgreSQL on my database running the query:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu;
```

(I got this from http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpython.html)

But I'm getting this error:

```
ERRO:  não pôde acessar arquivo "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
********** Error **********
ERRO: não pôde acessar arquivo "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
```

How to install this in an automated way? I need to install it on many computers.

Comment: just see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21641465/3682599)

Comment: I need python version 2.x :/
I'm working with NLTK.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Typically this error message is a misleading one emitted by the Windows API `LoadLibrary` call. What it actually means is closer to:

> Error when loading `plpython2.dll`: Cannot find dependency DLL `python27.dll` on `PATH`

but instead Windows just acts like it is `plpython2.dll` its self that could not be loaded.

You can tell if this is the issue by checking the `lib` directory of your PostgreSQL install for a `plpython2.dll`. If it's there, but you get this error, then it's a missing Python runtime. If there's no `plpython2.dll` at all then [your PostgreSQL install is missing plpython2, something I'm raising with the packaging team](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/54213117.9000501@2ndquadrant.com).

If you have `plpython2.dll` but it won't load, you need to install the Python runtime that matches the PostgreSQL version. It must be the same Python major version as was used to compile PostgreSQL, e.g. if Python 2.7 was used to compile PostgreSQL, Python 2.6 won't work to run plpython.

It'd be nice if installing the required runtime was automated via the installer, but at present it isn't. <strike>[It's also not properly documented, which I'll take up with the packaging team](http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/0/3945.page#14260)</strike> The correct runtime to install is now documented in `doc\installation-notes.html` inside the install directory, which you can also get to via *PostgresSQL 9.3 -> Documentation -> Installation Notes* in the Start menu.

For older relases that lack this information in their "installation notes" file, if you're not sure what version of Python is required you can use [`depends.exe` (dependency walker)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which Python DLL it's linked to. You need the same architecture of Python too - if you're installing 64-bit PostgreSQL you need 64-bit Python, etc.

The PostgreSQL 9.3 packages require Python 27. So go download Python 2.7 from http://python.org/ (not ActiveState, they aren't necessarily compatible). Make sure Python is added to the `PATH` by the installer (it's an option when you run the installer). Then re-try after re-starting PostgreSQL.

You can automate installation of Python with:

```
start /wait msiexec /i python-2.7.3.amd64.msi /qb /passive TARGETDIR=%SystemDrive%\Python27_x64 ALLUSERS=1
```

where `python-2.7.3.amd64.msi` is the filename of the Python binary you installed, and you're installing the 64-bit version to `C:\Python27_x64`. Adjust as desired.

Comment: _" if Python 2.7 was used to compile PostgreSQL, Python 2.6 won't work to run plpython."_?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid The have different DLL names (sonames). `plpython2.dll` will be linked to `python27.dll` and won't find `python26.dll` if it's present. Even if it was, Python isn't ABI compatible across major releases. Open `plpython2.dll` with `depends.exe` to see what I mean.

Comment: I think you meant to say "If Python 2.7 was used to compile plpython", no?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Well, sure, but plpython is a contrib that's packaged and distributed with PostgreSQL. In practice there's little difference.

Comment: The documentation doesn't seem to mention this **anywhere**, but the Windows builds of PostgreSQL 9.3 don't come with any support for `plypython2u` anymore. The `plpython2.dll` simply doesn't exist on my system. So it's necessary to upgrade to Python 3.2 to use with PG 9.3 builds unless you want to roll your own. More details here: http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/2878.page

Comment: @DanLenski That refers to PostgreSQL 9.1.0. But really, no plpython2? That doesn't seem right...

Comment: @Craig, I'm stumped too... But my stock amd64 MSI install of Pg9.3 is most definitely missing `pgpython2.dll`! Would be delighted to hear this was an accidental omission and there's a straightforward way to get it back in the standard build. Especially since the manual still says Python 2.x is the default!

Comment: @DanLenski MSI install? The PostgreSQL installers aren't MSIs. Where'd you download this from?

Comment: You're right, it's an .exe rather than a .msi; the aforementioned DLL is missing from a fresh install of 9.3.5 on Win7. http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-x64.exe

Comment: @DanLenski Ugh, plpython2 appears to be missing from my install too. I'll raise it on the mailing list... done; thread at http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/54213117.9000501@2ndquadrant.com

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked just installing Python 3.3. Previously I had 2.7 and 3.4, but non of them was the want it wanted.

I have PostgreSQL 9.4 x64 running on Windows 7